# how to create a fix header in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I refer https://www.mageplaza.com/sticky-header-component-magento-2.html
for the sticky header.

I have used the line of code:

```
<container name="sticky">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/sticky</item>
   <item name="toolbarProvider" xsi:type="string">cms_page_listing.cms_page_listing.listing_top</item>
   <item name="listingProvider" xsi:type="string">cms_page_listing.cms_page_listing.cms_page_columns</item>
   </item>
</argument>
</container>
```

I am trying, but still header is not fix at top. what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this piece of javascript code to your custom.js file and you can call this custom.js file either in `default_head_blocks.xml` or `requirejs-config.js`

```
require([ "jquery" ], function($){

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky'))){
    $('#header-2').addClass('sticky');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('#header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
});
```

and then add some css to this sticky class like this

```
#header.sticky {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #325052;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i'm new in magento, i didnot create a custom.js file i just add this code in... vendor\magento\module-cms\view\adminhtml\ui_component\cms_page_listing.xml. so i need to create a custom.js file?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    ...
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    ...
</listingToolbar>
```

Please share your full block of code if it is not working.